# Adding `exec "pass"` to a function allows modifications of locals() to be reflected in the namespace?

Tags: python, namespaces

Reading the answer to the question, [What's the difference between globals(), locals(), and vars()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars), The following explanation was given for how `locals()` works:

> if locals() is called inside a function it constructs a dictionary of the function namespace as of that moment and returns it -- any further name assignments are not reflected in the returned dictionary, and any assignments to the dictionary are not reflected in the actual local namespace

In a comment, it was mentioned that

> The part "and any assignments to the dictionary are not reflected in the actual local namespace" might be worded a bit to definite.

linking to the following code:

```
def f():
    exec "pass"
    locals()["x"] = 42
    print(x)
f()
```

This returns `42` (at least in CPython 2.7). Without the line `exec "pass"` python throws a `NameError` because it can't find `'x'`. This fits with the definition that changes to the dictionary returned by `locals()` inside a function are not reflected in the namespace. Why does adding the line `exec "pass"` allow these changes to be reflected? Is this somehow tricking python into thinking it has excited the function?

Comment: Don't rely on it because such thing was removed from Python 3.

Comment: I should be clear. I have no intention of using this. I'm just fascinated that it works, and was wondering what implementation detail is behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534368/is-there-any-way-to-affect-locals-at-runtime/1535195#1535195) to another question has a nice explanation of what is going on.  Here is the summary:

> The presence of an exec statement causes Python 2 to compile f in a totally non-optimized fashion, so locals are in a dict instead of in an array as they normally would be. (The performance hit can be considerable).

Comment: It's funny. When I wrote this question I thought to myself "I wish Alex Martelli was still answering questions here, he'd be all over this." Turns out, I was right. Thanks.