# What is the opposite of unpacking **kwargs in Python?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I've been learning about Python decorators and to practice using them, I'm writing a logging decorator that records when a function is called, the `*args` and `**kwargs` passed to the function, and a `__repr__` of the function so it can be re-evaluated at a later time.

In Python, the `__repr__()` method of an object returns a string that sometimes can be used to re-create the object by passing that string to `eval()`. I'm trying to implement a form of `__repr__` for functions.

Since I'm using a decorator that will wrap any function, I won't know beforehand what the function's parameters are, so I need to use `*args` and `**kwargs` to construct the `__repr__`, which is a string that looks like:

```py
"function_name(positional_arg1, positional_arg2, keyword_arg1='some_value', keyword_arg2='other_value')"
```

**To create that string representation, I need to reconstruct an argument list from `**kwargs`**; that is, convert a dictionary in the form of `{'kwarg1': val1, 'kwarg2': val2}` to an argument list like: `kwarg1=val1, kwarg2=val2`.

(Note: unpacking `*args` to an argument list isn't a problem, since the tuple form of `args` is already an acceptable format for passing as positional arguments to a function after removing the parentheses from the tuple. That is, the `args` tuple: `('arg1', 'arg2')` simply becomes `'arg1', 'arg2'`. Thus, this question focuses on converting the `kwargs` dictionary back to an argument list.)

Below is what I have created so far. It works but isn't very elegant. **Is there a simpler way to perform the opposite of unpacking `kwargs`?**

*EDIT: I removed supplementary code (e.g., setting up the decorator) to focus on the question at hand: the reverse operation of unpacking.*

```py
def print_args(*args, **kwargs):
    # Generate the kwargs string representation
    kwargs_repr = ''
    # If no kwargs are passed, kwargs holds an empty dictionary (i.e., dict())
    if kwargs != dict():
        num_kwargs = len(kwargs)
        # Convert to format required for an argument list (i.e., key1=val1 rather than {key1: val1})
        for n, (kw, val) in enumerate(kwargs.items()):
            kwargs_repr += str(kw) + '='
            # If the value is a string, it needs extra quotes so it stays a string after being passed to eval().
            if type(val) == str:
                kwargs_repr += '"' + val + '"'
            else:
                kwargs_repr += str(val)
            # Add commas to separate arguments, up until the last argument
            if n < num_kwargs - 1:
                kwargs_repr += ', '
    repr = (
        "print_args("
        # str(args)[1:-1] removes the parentheses around the tuple
        f"{str(args)[1:-1] if args != tuple() else ''}"
        f"{', ' if args != tuple() and kwargs != dict() else ''}"
        f"{kwargs_repr})"
    )
    print(repr)
    return repr


returned_repr = print_args('pos_arg1', 'pos_arg2', start=0, stop=10, step=1)
```

Output:

```py
print_args('pos_arg1', 'pos_arg2', start=0, stop=10, step=1)
```

(Attribution: some inspiration for my technique came from this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717810/17005348).

**Notes on what I've tried so far**

- I know I can access the `args` and `kwargs` separately, like this:

```py
# If I know the name of the function 
# and have stored the args and kwargs passed to the function:
any_func(*args, **kwargs)

# Or, more generally:
kwargs = str(kwargs)[1:-1].replace(': ', '=').replace("'", '')
eval(
    # func_name holds the __name__ attribute of the function
    func_name 
    + '(' 
    + str(args)[1:-1] 
    + ',' 
    + str(kwargs) 
    + ')'
)
```

... but I'd like to use the `repr` form if possible, to mimic the syntax used for creating an object (i.e., `eval(repr(obj))`) and to avoid the messy string concatenations used in the generic version.

- List/tuple comprehensions: my attempts haven't worked because each key-value pair becomes a string, rather than the entire arguments list as a whole, which means that `eval()` doesn't recognize it as a list of keyword arguments. For example:

```py
print(tuple(str(k) + '=' + str(v) for k, v in kwargs.items()))
```

outputs `('key1=val1', 'key2=val2')` instead of `('key1=val1, key2=val2')`.

- Using the `repr()` function, like: `repr(func(*args, **kwargs))`. This hasn't worked because the `func()` is evaluated first, so `repr()` just returns a string representation of the value returned by `func()`.

Comment: One way of doing it is to call the function like so: `func(**{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2})`, which is equivalent to `func(arg1=1, arg2=2)`.

Comment: `In Python, the __repr__() method of an object returns a string that can be used to re-create the object by passing that string to eval()` This is only sort of true - there are lots of cases where this doesn't work. For example: `repr(print)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @NickODell, I appreciate it and I've updated the question to say "the `__repr__()` method of an object returns a string that _sometimes_ can be used to re-create the object...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some serious caveats here, as not everything passed to any type of keyword argument will necessarily have a good representation and the representation may not work as you expect (reconstructing a copy of the original when evaluated).

Having said that, something like this:

```
def print_args(*args, **kwargs):
    print(', '.join(map(repr, args)),
          ', '.join(f'{k}={repr(v)}' for k, v in kwargs.items()))


print_args(1, 'test', [1, 2, 3], a='word', b={'key': 1, 'another': 2})
```

Output:

```
1, 'test', [1, 2, 3] a='word', b={'key': 1, 'another': 2}
```

Note: I didn't take the trouble of printing a comma between the two sections, I assume it's obvious what's going on there. But in case it annoys you:

```
def print_args(*args, **kwargs):
    print(', '.join(list(map(repr, args)) + 
                    [f'{k}={repr(v)}' for k, v in kwargs.items()]))
```

Output:

```
1, 'test', [1, 2, 3], a='word', b={'key': 1, 'another': 2}
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you @Grismar for your helpful (and fast!) response. Much appreciated. `.join()` was just what I was looking for.