# Assign a numeric value that is returned from a function by using exec command

Tags: python, python-2.7, exec

I need to assign a numeric value, which is returned from a function, to a variable name by using exec() command:

```
def func1(x,y):
    return x+y

def main(x,y,n):
    x=3; y=5; n=1
    t = exec("func%s(%s,%s)" % (n,x,y))
    return t**2

main(3,5,1)
```

I have many functions like "func1", "func2" and so on... I try to return `t = func1(x,y)` with the`exec("func%s(%s,%s)" % (n,x,y))` statement. However, I cannot assign a value, returned from`exec()`.

There is a partly similar question on [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696303/function-internally-using-execastring-with-a-variable-definition-inside-astrin), but it is written for Python3 and is also not applicable to my case.

How can we resolve this problem or is there a more elegant way to perform such an operation, maybe without the use of`'exec()'`?

By the way, as `"func%s(%s,%s)" % (n,x,y)` is a statement, I used exec. Or should I better use eval?

Comment: Why are you doing any of this? It seems a really strange design.

Comment: More specifically: why have all these functions and then refer to them by name, rather than e.g. having them in a data structure of some kind? (e.g., if they are all the sort of thing you can put into a lambda, a dict whose values are lambdas?).

Comment: Recommendations about other possible ways are also very welcome! :)

Comment: Also: Why do you say that "func(...)" is a statement? It looks like an expression to me. If you have to do things this way, then yes, you want eval rather than exec -- but, again, why?

Comment: It would be useful to have more context. What are all these functions? Why are there so many? Why are you referring to them by name like this? If the details are confidential, I'm sure you can be strategically vague or make up a close-enough cover story...

Comment: I will think about the implementation of your proposed way, but that would probably be quite difficult because, those functions (func1 in my example above) call other functions, which is quite different from each other... But thanks for the great idea, that would be really a neat way and I will try to do that.

Comment: In that case, indeed that might not be a good design. Again, with more information about what you're actually trying to achieve it's probably possible to make better recommendations. For instance, are you basically making your own little programming language (or, at a lower level, a virtual machine)? If so, it might be better to actually make one, putting in a bit more infrastructure now for cleaner code later.

Comment: Actually, I am not clear with whether `func%s(%s,%s)" % (n,x,y)` is a statement or an expression. I thought it was a statement...

Comment: It is not that much hard stuff; it is just a numeric solution algorithm. It is not confidential but, even if I copy+paste some of them here, it would be really long...

Comment: I wasn't suggesting copying-and-pasting anything! But more information would be nice -- "a numeric solution algorithm" could mean so many different things. Are we talking e.g. about different algorithms for solving differential equations (Runge-Kutta of different degrees, assorted predictor-corrector schemes, etc.), or something like that? I'm having trouble why you'd need a very large number of functions with such similar interfaces.

Comment: Another obvious candidate design: make a bunch of classes, each with a method of the same name that does whatever this thing is, and then what you pass to functions like your `main` above is the class, or an instance of that class. So, e.g., you might have a class `ODESolver` with a method `solve` and subclasses with names like `RungeKuttaODESolver`, each subclass having its own `solve` method, and then you'd call `main(RungeKuttaODESolver,3,4)` or whatever.

Comment: In fact, that approach is near enough to the canonical way to do this sort of thing in a language that supports it that I'm going to go ahead and make an answer saying so. Of course it may turn out that it doesn't meet your specific needs, in which case knowing those needs will probably make it possible to come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost always a **really bad idea** to get at functions and variables using their names as strings (or bits of their names as integers, as in the example code in the question). One reason why is that `eval` or `exec` can do literally *anything* and you generally want to avoid using code constructs whose behaviour is so hard to predict and reason about.

So here are two ways to get similar results with less pain.

First: Instead of passing around magic index numbers, like the `1` in the code above, pass *the actual function* which is, itself, a perfectly reasonable value for a variable in Python.

```
def main(x,y,f):
  return f(x,y)**2

main(3, 5, func1)
```

(Incidentally, the definition of `main` in the question throws away the values of `x`,`y`,`n` that are passed in to it. That's probably a mistake.)

Second: Instead of making these mere *functions*, make them *methods* on classes, and pass around not the functions but either the classes themselves or instances of the classes.

```
class Solver:
  def solve(self, x,y): return "eeeek, not implemented"

class Solver1:
  def solve(self, x,y): return x+y

def main(x, y, obj):
  return obj.solve(x,y)**2

main(3, 5, Solver1())
```

Which of these is the better approach depends on the details of your application. For instance, if you actually have multiple "parallel" sets of functions -- as well as your `func1`, `func2`, etc., there are also `otherfunc1`, `otherfunc2` etc. -- then this is crying out for an object-oriented solution (the second approach above).

In general I would argue for the second approach; it tends to lead to cleaner code as your requirements grow.

Comment: Second approach helped me a lot. I changed my code appropriately and now, I do not need to make such a definition. Thanks a lot!