# Python exec() NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, exec

Why am I getting a `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`?  This code is under a function in a class.  `main_root` should be accessible anywhere in the class since it was initialized under `__init__` as `self.main_root = an element`.  The first parameter of the function is `self` too.

```
root_string = "self.main_root[0][1]"

globals()
code_locals = {'temp_string':""}

command_string = "temp_string = str(" + root_string + ".tag) + str(" + root_string + ".attrib)"
exec(command_string,globals(),code_locals)
```

If I set `root_string = "main_root[0][1]"` then I will get `main_root is undefined`.  Even if I try to assign `main_root = copy.deepcopy(self.main_root)` beforehand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does exec work with locals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need access `self` variable in the `exec` statement, you should pass the third parameter with `locals()`, not `code_locals`, in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
root_string =self.main_root[0][1]
```

or if you want it as string,do it as

```
root_string = str(self.root[0][1])
```

you have to convert a variable to type(string,int,etc) you want you cannot initialize it as " self.main_root[0][1]"

Comment: Im using the exec() which uses a string. Also the address, in this example " [0][1]" is from another function. How would you propose your solution if the address [0][1] came to you as a string