# NameError: name 'self' is not defined IN EXEC/EVAL

Tags: python, exec, eval, self, nameerror

I was coding something, and there was an error in one part.
But I can't find why the error occurs.

Code (Sample; similar to the error part):

```
class Test:
def __init__(self,a=0):
    self.x = a
    self.l = [2**x for x in range(a)]  #<--- self.l = [1,2,4,8,16]
    self.base()

def base(self):
    expr = "self.l{0} = [self.l[x]+{0} for x in range(self.x)]" #<--- when i=4, self.l4 = [5,6,8,12,20]
    for i in range(self.x):
        exec(expr.format(i))

w = Test(5)
print(w.l4)
```

So I thought that I get this:

```
[5, 6, 8, 12, 20]
```

BUT,

```
File "D:/Documents and Settings/Desktop/py/py/test2.py", line 12, in <module>
  w = Test(5)
File "D:/Documents and Settings/Desktop/py/py/test2.py", line 5, in __init__
  self.base()
File "D:/Documents and Settings/Desktop/py/py/test2.py", line 10, in base
  exec(expr.format(i))
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1, in <listcomp>

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does exec work with locals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's no need for eval or exec here.

```
for i in range(self.x):
    setattr(self, "l{}".format(i), [self.l[x]+i for x in range(self.x)])
```

Although I don't know why you want to do this; better to keep it as a list rather than dynamically set attributes.

Answer (score 0):

### If you use a for loop instead of the list comprehension

it will works.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,a=0):
        self.x = a
        self.l = [2**x for x in range(a)]  #<--- self.l = [1,2,4,8,16]
        self.base()

    def base(self):
        # expr = "self.l{0} = [self.l[x]+{0} for x in range(self.x)]" #<--- when i=4, self.l4 = [5,6,8,12,20]
        expr = '''
self.l{0} = []
for x in range(self.x):
    self.l{0}.append(self.l[x]+{0})
'''
        for i in range(self.x):
            expr_formated = expr.format(i)
            print(expr_formated)
            exec(expr_formated)

w = Test(5)
print(w.l4)
```

The list comprehension is actually using lamda function, as you can see in [the python document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). `squares = [x**2 for x in range(a)]` is actually `squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(a)))`. **(EDIT: recently I find that this is not accurate, see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72991388/9758790), they are not the same, but they work in a similar way;perhaps one can still uses the `lambda` to understand this if doesn't want to refer to python assembly)** However, creating a function object (lamda function here) inside the `exec()` will results in problems. I post [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72335222/9758790) here explaining why creating a function object doesn't work as expected. In short, the `__closure__` of the defined lamda function is set to None, making the varible `a` unavailable when the lamda function is called.

### If you insist on using lambda function.

There is also another solution. Please refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72340953/9758790) to previous mentioned question for more information.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,a=0):
        self.x = a
        self.l = [2**x for x in range(a)]  #<--- self.l = [1,2,4,8,16]
        self.base()

    def base(self):
        expr = """
def closure_helper_func(self):
    self.l{0} = [self.l[x]+{0} for x in range(self.x)]
closure_helper_func(self)""" #<--- when i=4, self.l4 = [5,6,8,12,20]
        for i in range(self.x):
            expr_formated = expr.format(i)
            # print(expr_formated)
            exec(expr_formated)

w = Test(5)
print(w.l4)
```