# Python3 - exec() giving me syntax error for if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, interpreter

I'm creating my own programming language. The interpreter is written in Python.

I'm trying to add an 'if/else' command. The syntax is:

```
if "hello" == $myString |> goto somewhere
else |> goto somewhere_else
```

Instead of implementing the operator logic on my own, I decided to just use the Python `exec()` command. This is what I am doing (simplified):

```
task = task.split(' |> ', 1)  # Split on first occurence of "|> "
clause = task[0]
operation = task[1]

clauseCheck = False
clause = clause + ": clauseCheck = True" # So we can run it as python code to eval
eval(clause)  # if the clause evals to true, clauseCheck will be True

if clauseCheck:
    parse(operation)
```

And here's the error I'm getting (using `if 7 != 2 |> ...`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

...

  File "interpret.py", line 139, in parse
    eval(clause)  # if the clause evals to true, clauseCheck will be True
  File "<string>", line 1
    if 7 != 2: print('True') ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried everything I can think of - I've added a newline to the string given to `eval()` with and without indentation, I've tried just printing 'true' instead of setting a variable and I've tried with a different if statement.

How can I get my code to properly evaluate the if statements?

Comment: what is the question and where's the error ?

Comment: @coder submitted too early, adding now

Comment: @TheoC I still do not see an error raised.. That being said, `eval` is not only tricky but dangerous too. I would propose `literal_eval` from `ast`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I have added the error I'm getting, do you mean you aren't getting an error when you run the code I provided?

Comment: `eval` is for evaluating expressions, not executing statements. Since the `if-statement` is a statement, you'd need to use `exec`. But `exec` in Python3 never modifies locals. Instead, you need to pass a local namespace (dict) to `exec` and then access the result from the local namespace dict. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1463370/190597.

Comment: @unutbu Do you mean I could pass `eval` something like `7 == 7` or `7 != 2` and it'd return `True` for both? That could be just what I need.

Comment: @TheoC No, I mean that the traceback you posted seems to be missing something.

Comment: @TheoC: Sure you could. (Try it out in the interpreter!) But to execute the `clause`, you'd need `ns = dict(); exec(clause, globals(), ns)`. Followed by `if ns['clauseCheck']: ...`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Full traceback: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interpret.py", line 150, in <module>
    parse(tasks[currentLine])  # parse the task at the current line in tasks
  File "interpret.py", line 139, in parse
    eval(clause)  # if the clause evals to true, clauseCheck will be True
  File "<string>", line 1
    if 7 != 2: print('True')
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: @unutbu **THANK YOU!** That is just what I wanted and actually means I can use a much more elegant solution.

Comment: You know that that `task.split("|> ")` will fail if there is a string like `if "foo |> bar" |> ...` in the condition, making programs written in that language vulnerable to all sorts of "code injection", right?

Comment: @tobias_k I'm aware of that and working on a way to fix it.