# Python: variable defined by exec() not defined in a function scope

Tags: python, scoping

Consider the following code

```
g = {}
l = {}

exec("a = 1", g, l)
exec("""
def test():
    print(a)
""", g, l)

l['test']()
```

This results in

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    l['test']()
  File "<string>", line 3, in test
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

This only seems to happen when I use separate dictionaries for globals and locals. If I instead use `g = l = {}` it works as expected.

Why is the variable defined by the first `exec` not available in the function defined by the second `exec`?

It's worth noting that the variable ends up in `l`, not `g`.

This seems similar to [How does exec work with locals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals), execpt it's not quite the same because here I am using a real dictionary for `locals`.

Comment: The lesson to be learned is to not use `exec` or `eval`.

Comment: Short answer, `globals` and `locals` must be the same mapping to act as if you were executing in the module-level scope. If you pass two different mappings, it is executed like a class definition. Just as if you define `a = classvar` in a class block,  methods won't have access to `a` .

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you should have written that as an answer. That's as clear as it gets.