# What are the scoping rules for exec?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, python-exec

I have (as it seems to me) some basic understanding of Python scoping rules (based on studying of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/8554766)).

I have also learned from the [documentation on `exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), that it takes `globals` and `locals` as optional arguments, and that:

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope.

---

**NOTE: all examples below assume usage of Python 3.**

With that said, I have recently stumbled onto the case, which confused me a bit:

```
def test(passed_data):
    local_result = 5
    exec("print(passed_data)")
    exec("print(local_result)")

    return local_result

print (test('whatever'))
```

running code above results in:

```
whatever
5
5
```

Here, it is evident that `exec` has access to `test`s locals (`passed_data` and 'local_result').

Though if we will try to change any of them:

```
def test(passed_data):
    local_result = 5
    exec("print(passed_data)")
    exec("print(local_result)")

    exec("passed_data = 222")
    exec("local_result = 111")

    exec("print(passed_data)")
    exec("print(local_result)")

    return local_result

print (test('whatever'))
```

it will result in:

```
whatever
5
whatever
5
5
```

Using `global` inside `exec`:

```
def test(passed_data):
    local_result = 5

    exec("print(local_result)")
    exec("global local_result; local_result = 111")
    exec("print(local_result)")

    return local_result

print (test('whatever'))
```

gives the same result (of course, since `local_result` is local to the scope of `test`):

```
5
5
5
```

What enables us to chance `local_result` via `exec` — is defining it using `global`:

```
def test(passed_data):
    global local_result
    local_result = 5

    exec("print(local_result)")
    exec("global local_result; local_result = 111")
    exec("print(local_result)")

    return local_result

print (test('whatever'))
```

This gives us:

```
5
111
111
```

---

It seems to me that I'm just missing some basic understanding of Python scoping or the mechanics of `exec`, to grasp this case.

Nevertheless, I would like to understand the following:

1. Why `exec` is able to print variable from the function scope, without using `global`, but is not able to change it?
2. My understanding is that (**given `globals` and `locals` are omitted**) `exec` will execute any Python code, within the scope it is called from, as if this code was just in the source (without `exec`), where (and how) am I wrong in this assumption?

P.S.: I understand that changing local variable via `exec` is not 'right thing to do', I seek the understanding of `exec` scoping rules just for the sake of learning.

Comment: Local variables are subject to optimisations that prevent them from being modified dynamically. A similar example is the note in https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals. Global variables don't have these restrictions, but it takes a `global` statement outside the exec for the compiler to recognise a variable as global rather than local.

Comment: Checkout this answer I just posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/49208472/2867928

Comment: @AlexHall, thanks for pointing out related doc section!

Comment: @Kasramvd, I've checked your answer — it explains the same thing indeed. Thanks!