# How to use exec to assign list to variable according to dictionary in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exec, local-variables

I want to assign list to variable, while `list` and `variable` are both stored in a dictionary `measurements`. This is the Python 2 version of `measurements` with less variables:

```
measurements = {'tg': [8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.520e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16, 4.305e+16, 2.203e+16]}

def f():
    for key,val in measurements.items():
        exec(key + ' = val') in globals(),locals()
    print (tg)
f()
```

However, as mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals), it's not suitable for Python 3.
If I write the code like this:

```
measurements = {'tg': [8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.520e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16, 4.305e+16,
 2.203e+16]}

def f():
    for key,val in measurements.items():
        ldict = {}
        exec(key + ' = val', globals(),ldict)
        key = ldict[key]
        # exec(key + ' = val') in globals(),locals()
    print (tg)
f()
```

I got this error: `NameError: name 'val' is not defined`

Comment: try this: exec(key + ' = val', globals(),ldict) -> exec('{} = {}'.format(key, val), globals(),ldict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ldict = {}` trick creates a substitute local namespace for use inside `exec`. This is useful because the dict returned by `locals()` doesn't write through to your actual locals like it used to in Python 2.

But that substitute namespace `{}` is empty. It doesn't contain your `locals()`, therefore it doesn't have `val` in it. Try using `ldict = {**locals()}` instead to copy the contents of your locals to the substitute locals `ldict`.

---

Remember that you have to read all the "locals" created by exec from the ldict. Thus, `print(tg)` won't work either, because it was only ever assigned in one of the substitute local namespaces. You probably don't want to make a new one every loop. Just `.update()` one you make in advance.

```
def f():
    ldict = {}
    for key,val in measurements.items():
        ldict.update(locals())
        exec(key + ' = val', globals(),ldict)
        key = ldict[key]
        # exec(key + ' = val') in globals(),locals()
    print (ldict['tg'])
```

---

The number and names of locals must be known in advance by the compiler in Python3 for performance optimizations. (This doesn't apply to `globals()`, they still write through.)

If you know them in advance, you can just assign from them, e.g.

```
tg = ldict['tg']
print(tg)
```

If you need more than one you could unpack a dictionary into locals, like

```
a, b, c = (ldict[key] for key in ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Or you could dump the whole dict into a simple namespace and access them with `.` instead of `[]`.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

# ...

ns = SimpleNamespace(**ldict)
print(ns.tg)
```

You could also just `exec` any code that needs the new locals, since you can give `exec` the `ldict` namespace.

```
exec("print(tg)", globals(), ldcit)
```

---

I understand that your example code may be simplified from the original, but it does not appear to need `exec` at all. It is generally considered bad form to use `exec` unless you absolutely need it, since it confuses static analysis tools and compiling strings at runtime is slow, especially if repeated in a loop like that.

If you must use exec, it's better to put the loop inside the exec string (use triple quotes) than the exec call inside the loop. That way the string only has to be compiled once, instead of for each loop.

Comment: After changing ldict={} to ldict = {**locals()}, it's the same error.

Comment: Thanks. But, I need to use `tg` directly instead of calling the dictionary again. Do you have some suggestions for this?

Comment: @XinZhang out of curiosity, which suggestion did you pick?

Comment: Finally, I choose this one `a, b, c = (ldict[key] for key in ['a', 'b', 'c'])`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
measurements = {'tg': [8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.520e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16, 4.305e+16, 2.203e+16]}

def f():
    for key,val in measurements.items():
        exec('{} = {}'.format(key, val))
    print (tg)

    local = locals()
    for key in measurements.keys():
        print 'Key: ', key, ', Value: ', local[key]
f()
```

python3:

```
measurements = {'tg': [8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.520e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16, 4.305e+16, 2.203e+16]}

def f():
    for key,val in measurements.items():
        exec('global {};{} = {}'.format(key, key, val))
    print ('tg: ', tg)

    vars = globals()
    for key in measurements.keys():
        print ('Key: ', key, ', Value: ', vars[key])
f()
```

output:

```
[8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.52e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16, 4.305e+16, 2.203e+16]
Key:  tg , Value:  [8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.52e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16, 4.305e+16, 2.203e+16]
```

Comment: `exec('{} = {}'.format(key, val))` doesn't work for Python 3. `NameError: name 'tg' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks. If I'm using `measurements = {'tg': np.array([8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.520e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16, 4.305e+16,
 2.203e+16])}` instead of list. I'll get this error:`    global tg;tg = [8.184e+16 8.345e+16 8.045e+16 8.520e+16 8.322e+16 7.622e+16 4.305e+16
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: use np.array() inside exec `>>> measurements = {'tg': [8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.520e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16, 4.305e+16, 2.203e+16]}
>>> for key,val in measurements.items():
...     exec('global {};{} = np.array({})'.format(key, key, val))
... 
>>> tg
array([8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.520e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16,
       4.305e+16, 2.203e+16])`

Answer (score 0):

Years later, but I've since realized that you can (ab)use the temporary namespace made in class declarations to get a write-through locals() namespace inside of functions. This allows you to translate the Python 2 version pretty directly:

```
measurements = {'tg': [8.184e+16, 8.345e+16, 8.045e+16, 8.520e+16, 8.322e+16, 7.622e+16, 4.305e+16, 2.203e+16]}

def f():
    class _:
        for key,val in measurements.items():
            exec(key + ' = val', globals(), locals())
        print (tg)

f()
```