# strange behaviour of locals() after exec()

Tags: python

I have a function that accepts a string with source code with some definitions, `exec`s it - and then gets new definitions from `locals()`.

```
def do_exec(code):
    exec(code)
    print(locals()['x'])

do_exec('x = 5')
```

this works as expected.

However, when I try to do this:

```
def do_exec_2(code):
    exec(code)
    x = locals()['x']
    print(x)


do_exec_2('x = 5')
```

I get an error:

```
KeyError: 'x'
```

why is that?

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals)

Comment: indeed it is! thanks. Didn't thing of googling first this time.