# Python3: inject a recursive function into exec() in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

In python3, if a function with recursive invoking is injected into `exec()` in a function, I got an error.
For example, below code

```py
def B(pys):
    exec(pys)

pys="""
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        r = 1
    else:
        r = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
    return r

print(fibonacci(3))
"""
B(pys)
```

will raise NameError.

```sh
$ py -3.8 testrecursivefun.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testrecursivefun.py", line 14, in <module>
    B(pys)
  File "testrecursivefun.py", line 2, in B
    exec(pys)
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in fibonacci
NameError: name 'fibonacci' is not defined
```

If I run exec(pys) directly under the module, the exception disappeared.

The reason has been described in another question [How does exec work with locals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals). But I still don't know how I can figure out the recursive invoking in `exec()`. Because the function name is dynamic for me. I cannot add it to `locals()` to `exec()`. Who can help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of an answer, you can wrap your code in a function so the recursive function is in its local scope:

```
import textwrap

def B(pys):
    exec(pys, globals(), {})

pys="""
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        r = 1
    else:
        r = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
    return r

print(fibonacci(11))
"""

def wrap(s):
    return "def foo():\n" \
           "{}\n" \
           "foo()".format(textwrap.indent(s, ' ' * 4))

B(wrap(pys))
```

Generally, reconsider using exec.

Comment: It's brilliant. Thank you so much. @zxzak. Do you know the reason. Why the second layer inner function can record the itself in local variable list, but the first layer can't? Is it a python's bug. Why did python3 developer close the bug report https://bugs.python.org/issue4831?

Answer (score -1):

I actually got interested in your question, so I started researching on this topic. Seems like the simple solution to your problem is to:

1. First compile the string to code using `compile` function in python
2. Then execute the compiled code using `exec` function

Here is the sample solution:

```
psy="""
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        r = 1
    else:
        r = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
    return r

print(fibonacci(3))
"""

def B(psy):
    code = compile(psy, '<string>', 'exec')
    exec(code, globals())

B(psy)
```

Here compile takes three parameters:

First is the *code in string format*, Second is the *filename hint* which we used  as we take string as code itself, and third can be one of *'exec', 'eval' and 'single'*.

This [link](https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/) contains detail explanation of how you should use exec and eval in python. Do check them out for detail explanation.

Comment: Did you try to run your code? It doesn't work. I tried the same method before I raise this question.

Comment: This executes the code in the global scope, introducing namespace pollution and clobbering issues. Also, the `compile` step is unnecessary. `exec` will automatically compile strings. `compile` is primarily useful if you want to save the bytecode and execute it repeatedly, or if you want to inspect or modify the bytecode.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning. I am sure, I need to go deep on this. Could you provide me any supporting links where I can study on detail :)