# Python exec() recursive output?

Tags: python, recursion

I have this python code that runs other code and I can get the result as such:

```
def codeTester():
 try:
    loc = {}
    exec(code, {}, loc)
 except Exception as e:
   #Excpetion handling....
 result = loc['result']
```

loc after running would be a dictionary and result key would have the output of the function.

However this does not work with recursive functions. According to [Using exec() with recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871887/using-exec-with-recursive-functions) and [Python3: inject a recursive function into exec() in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835853/python3-inject-a-recursive-function-into-exec-in-a-function) I need to wrap the code which I do using the function inside the second link:

```
def wrap(s):
   return "def foo():\n" \
          "{}\n" \
          "foo()".format(textwrap.indent(s, ' ' * 4))
```

This wraps the 'code' with that function and now The recursive code runs but loc[] does not hold the result. It just holds a key called 'foo' which has this value <function foo at 0x000001F208386F70>. How can I get the output in this situation? or is there a better method to achieving this?

edit: I should note that something like `exec(code, locals(), locals())` does also work but its still the same problem where I cant access the output of exec()

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the described behaviour. Could you add a little example code that does?

Comment: why do you use `exec()`? Why do you create code using `string`?

Comment: @furas I have to take code inputted as a string and run it through a complier, I don't know of a better way