# Why can't a python string change a global variable from inside a class?

Tags: python, class, global

I am trying to make a class that is given a value, then executes a string in a list of strings based on the index given in order to change global variables. But I cannot figure out why the string that is executed cannot change the values of var1 and var0.

```
global var0, var1

class Change:
    def __init__(self, executed):
        self.executed = executed
    def changeGlobals(self):
        global var0, var1
        exec(self.executed)

var0 = 0
var1 = 1

executed = 'var0 = var0+1; var1 = var1+1;'

var = Change(executed)
var.changeGlobals()



# is supposed to print 'var0 is 1, var1 is 2'
print('var0 is '+str( var0 )+', var1 is '+str( var1 ))
# actually prints 'var0 is 0, var1 is 1'
```

Comment: Can we take a step back and talk about the broader context and _why_ you're trying to do this?

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals) question, and may have the same answer (I don't use `exec`, so I can't say for sure).

Comment: your `global` staement in `changeGlobals` isn't going to affect the string that is being executed. It is assigning to a dict returned from `locals()`. In any case, almost certainly, this is not a good idea. Note also, `global var0, var1` is pointless at the top of the global scope.

Comment: So, you'd have to use a string like `Change("global var0; var0 = var0 + 1").changeGlobals()`. Alternatively, you could pass `globals()` as the second and third argument to `exec`, although that will make *everything* executed global. But again, this fundamentally seems like a bad design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not changing values of the variable inside the changeGlobals() method, instead change like this:

```
global var0, var1

class Change:
    def __init__(self, executed):
        self.executed = executed
    def changeGlobals(self):
        global var0, var1
        var0 += 1
        var1 += 1
        exec(self.executed)
```

Another way is to change `executed = 'var0 = var0+1; var1 = var1+1;'`  to `executed = 'global var0, var1; var0 = var0+1; var1 = var1+1;'` actually found that the global definition inside the passed string to exec works

Comment: But then what's the point of `exec(self.executed)`?

Comment: @WasifHasan OK, but that's a different solution. I'm asking about the first solution. If it's not useful, you should just remove it from the answer.