# Variable assignment with Python exec() from a PSQL table

Tags: python, exec, variable-assignment

I'm trying to fetch values from a **PSQL table** to dynamically trigger methods or assign variables **using Python exec()**.

Say we have a postgres table like so :

```
id |          commands           | flag_activ
---+-----------------------------+------------
1  | keyword = 'miscellaneous'   | TRUE
2  | keyword = 'multifarious'    | FALSE
3  | print('PRINT FOR DEMO')     | FALSE
```

My code :

```
conn = connect_db(host,database,user,password)
cur = conn.cursor()            
query = 'SELECT commands FROM table WHERE flag_activ = TRUE'             
cur.execute(query)   
res = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

At this point, if I `print(res)`, I get the output :

```
> keyword='miscellaneous'
```

which is the command that I'm trying to pass to the exec() method, in order to create a variable called `keyword`.

**PROBLEM :** when I call `exec(res)`, then I `print(keyword)`I get this error:

```
> NameError: name 'keyword' is not defined
```

**Expected output**:

```
> miscellaneous
```

Why is the variable assignment not being taken into account here ? What am I missing ?

**What I have tried :**

1. Debugging in a Python shell :

   ```
   >>> print(keyword)
   NameError: name 'keyword' is not defined
   >>> res = 'keyword = "miscellaneous"'
   >>> exec(res)
   >>> print(keyword)
   miscellaneous
   ```

> This works as expected.

2. Passing a method instead of a variable assignment. In the case of **row id n°3** :

   ```
   ...
   >>> query = 'SELECT commands FROM table WHERE id = 3'
   >>> cur.execute(query)
   >>> res = cur.fetchone()[0]
   >>> exec(res)
   PRINT FOR DEMO
   ```

> This also works as expected.

3. Declaring `keyword` as an empty string beforehand : the exec() method does not reassign the variable to the expected value `miscellaneous`.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks !

Comment: Is this code that fails executed inside function?

Comment: @buran Yes it is.

Comment: @buran Following up on your comment, I stumbled upon this [already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals). This should gave me answers. Thanks.

Comment: You can close the question as duplicate by accepting the suggested dupe reference