# import python library from existing process already imported

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm working with a python library (arcpy) that has a long import time (1-2min) due checks done against a license server. This makes debug sessions extremely slow when I'm re-running code multiple times.

Is there a way I can import the library to python process #1, and keep that process always live, then use that library from python process #2?

Something like:

| Script 1 | Script 2 |
| --- | --- |
| while True: | from script 1 import arcpy |
| import arcpy |  |

Have not tried approaches as I'm not even sure if something like this is feasible...Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), a simple example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python). Of course, you would have to set up the Listener to use the library in question. You could use `exec()` to make the listener run whatever code you send it and send back the response (in python3, `result` must be global or you need to pass `exec` a dictionary for local variables as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1463370/3984972)).

Client:

```py
conn.send("result=15")
print(conn.recv()) #15
```

Server:

```py
var cmd = conn.recv()
exec(cmd)
conn.send(result)
```