# getting local variables created with 'exec'

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a function wrapper that will automatically print every variable assignment made in the function. To do this I'm trying to use the `exec()` function on the wrapped functions code, then take the new local variables from the execution and print the dictionary:

```
def track_assignments(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        assignments = {}
        exec(func.__code__, globals(), assignments)
        for k, v in assignments.items():
            print(f"{k} = {v}")
    return wrapper

@track_assignments
def test():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = a * b
    print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

However, it's not working. The `assignments` dictionary is blank when the code executes, and I'm not sure why.

I've looked at various other questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-to-get-local-variables-updated-when-using-the-exec-call) for example, as well as the `exec` documentation, and I'm following the answers given, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Postscript: If anyone can think of a more efficient method of printing all variable asignments made in a function I would appreciate some new perspectives.

Comment: `func.__code__` is the entire function object. Calling `exec(func.__code__)` is analogous to `exec("func()")`, so of course its assignments occur in a different scope than the `locals` you're providing.

Comment: obligatory: why are you doing this? There may be a better solution. Must it be a runtime-decorator?

Comment: To echo @Gaberocksall this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why are you trying to do this? Your problem statement is also ambiguous since what you're attempting will not tell your about each assignment -- only that a local var was created (assuming what you're trying to do even worked as you expect).

Comment: @Gaberocksall that's not true, the problem is that the code object is optimized for a local scope and uses `STORE_FAST` opcode instead of `STORE_NAME`

Comment: @Gaberocksall ah, I see, that section of the code was via copilot, so I just blindly trusted it was working. As for why I'm doing this, I find myself using python as a calculator for homework assignments often, and I find it annoying to print off each intermittent variable every time, so I wanted to create a method that automatically did it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just starting with python, the magic required to make such decorator work is probably more black than you want.

I'll probably expand this answer tomorrow, here's quick&dirty solution that seems to work. If you're going to use it for anything but fun or learning, please think again and don't.

```py
import pprint
import sys

def track_assignments(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ns = {}

        def observer(frame, event, _):
            nonlocal ns
            if event == 'return' and frame.f_code.co_name == func.__name__:
                ns = dict(frame.f_locals)

        old_profile = sys.getprofile()
        sys.setprofile(observer)

        try:
            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            sys.setprofile(old_profile)

        pprint.pprint(ns)
        return ret

    return wrapper
```

What's going on? The core of this implementation is [`sys.setprofile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile), read the documentation to learn more about it and stack frames in general - such topic would be way too broad for a single answer.

The second condition (`frame.f_code.co_name == func.__name__`) is not strictly necessary: your function will be the last one in the call chain anyway, so its values will overwrite everything collected before. However, it's a good sanity check to confirm that we aren't doing something entirely wrong.

Comment: Wow, yeah I'm pretty new to python and a lot of that goes over my head but that works, thank you. This isn't anything critical, I'm just using it for convenience when using python as a calculator. Thank you for the help.